# R quantreg basksolve error

Tags: r, quantreg

When I install the quantreg package in R I get this warning:

```
> library(quantreg)
Loading required package: SparseM
Package SparseM (0.96) loaded.
       To cite, see citation("SparseM")


Attaching package: 'SparseM'

The following object(s) are masked from 'package:base':

    backsolve

Package quantreg (4.79) loaded.
        To cite, see citation("quantreg")
```

Then, after running a quantile regression:

```
sym.lm  = rq(Y ~ X1 + X2 + X3 + X4 + X5 + X6 + X7, data = myd, na.action = na.omit, method = "fn", model = TRUE)
summary(sym.lm)
Error in base::backsolve(r, x, k = k, upper.tri = upper.tri, transpose = transpose,  : 
  singular matrix in 'backsolve'. First zero in diagonal [1]
In addition: Warning message:
In summary.rq(sym.lm) : 21010 non-positive fis
```

Is this error related to the backsolve scope problem?

Comment: I would guess not. It seems likely that both versions would throw an error if the matrix it is provided is singular.

Comment: Maybe I should move the question to crossvalidated.

Comment: How can I migrate this question to cross validated?

Comment: Singularity of the Matrix has more to do with the data than the package. Also i noticed you did not specify a `tau`. Try specifying `tau=0.5` and try running regular `lm` so we can check on the data you are entering